# SOLR nested fields produces messy result

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I have a problem with SOLR.
The main motivation to do the thing I describe later was to remove the load from database into a SOLR. We are talking about an eshop which holds tons of products and where the static data (sometimes computed by a pretty "expensive" SQL queries) should be stored in SOLR.

The version of SOLR is **8.2**

These is actually no problem with common fields like *product name, product code* etc.. Problems started when I want to migrate the 1:N relations (for example product_tag - you can imagine something like NEW, PRETTY COOL, ... - where I want to store some fields - id, tag name and some boolean)

```
<entity name="product_tag"
    child="true"
    query="SELECT l.id, l.text as tag, l.eshop_relevant, sipt.stock_item_id as stock_item_id FROM product_tag l join stock_item_product_tag sipt on sipt.product_tag_id = l.id"
    cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache"
    where="stock_item_id=stock_item.id">
<field name="id" column="id" />
<field name="text" column="tag" />
<field name="eshop_relevant" column="eshop_relevant" />
```

The core which I want to extend looks like this (some fields were removed for simplicity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="xxx" version="1.6">

    <xi:include href="common-types.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>

    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

    <uniqueKey>code</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

As you can see, the main thing is code. Typical usage is some BE Spring API will call SOLR client with request asking for products with codes 1,2,3,4,5 and SOLR should give him all documents corresponding to given codes.

I tried to enhance the document with these fields

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="product_tag_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="product_tag_name" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="eshop_relevant" type="boolean" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```

To cover the 1:N relation with product tag (so product will hold "array" of product tags where each one holds its id, name a eshop_relevant boolean).

The result is not working. **The result is pretty messy**, sometimes its imports one product twice (so there are 2 documents with same code) while

**the "first" product has**

- product_tag.product_tag_id : "22" (its string and no other product tag related field)

**the "second" product has**

- product_tag_name: "SOME NAME"
- eshop_relevant: true
- product_tag_id : 22

I´ve tried many possbilities, googled for ages (even tried all SO threads corresponding to nested objects on SOLR), tried some online book about solr and nothing happened.

Comment: First; is there any reason you _really_ need nested fields? A multi-valued field composed of your product_tag and possibly any other necessary properties merged to a single field should suffice, depending on your usage.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, there could be for example (in some pretty crazy scenario when one product document can have a 100 product tags where I need all 3 properties - typical usage is when I receive the data, pass them to the front-end and there I use the ID, Name and boolean to display the tags. And there are many of these 1:N collection I need to wire to the document)

Comment: Sure, but why wouldn't a composite value like `ID|Name|1` etc. work? It'd give you the ability to create facets on unique combinations, you can filter on a selection (or index the ID in a separate field for filtering) by using wildcards: `fq=ID|*` and displaying it is a simple string split in the frontend (which can be abstracted away behind your data object if necessary).

Comment: @MatsLindh I dont really like an idea to have composite fields, there is need to parse it back. I saw there is possibility to store (or output) nested objects. Main usage is store as many composite data as possible to avoid unnecessary SQL queries while displaying some big entity on FE (in ideal situation it should be only one query to solr)

Comment: Don't underestimate the power (and sometimes necessity) of massaging your data in specific ways to handle specific use cases in document search engines. They're usually not a 1:1 mapping of all use cases. Solr does support nested JSON directly now (which ES did from the start), so you might want to look into that in that case - behind the scenes this is Solr (and ES) doing the mangling for you.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, thats what i wanted to do but (as I said in my question) i struggle to make it work.

Comment: Yes, but you're not submitting JSON; my suggestion was to do that instead of trying to make it work through DIH.